# define subdomain apache's vhost with lighttpd

Tags: apache, subdomain, lighttpd

Apache is runnig my server with port 80 and lighttpd with 81.

I defined vhost abc.com in apache. 
I want to define track.abc.com and all request goes to lighttpd. Is is possible to define track subdomain for abc.com in lighttpd?

Comment: Are you going to be using a redirect to send requests to `track.abc.com:81` or will you be using apache as a proxy which will send the request through to lighttpd? (I have no experience with that) You can configure lighttpd to handle subdomains, but your first problem will just be getting requests through to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I research and answer is Apache's ProxyPass option. First I configured my subdomain on Apache's vhost. and I added my subdomain's chost config file

```
ProxyPass / http://my_host_name:81/
```

Now, all my subdomains request goes to lighttp.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but rather than ports you need to have 2 separate IP addresses if you want to make regular request http://www.domainname.com in your browser. Otherwise you will be forced to call http://www.domainname.com if you intend to use the same IP address for both Apache and Lighttpd server.

You need to declare listening port in both Apache config and Lighttpd otherwise they both would try to bind IP address and port 80 which will result in error and only first server would start up.